# Vue3 Options API + Jest + vue test utils: nested function testing problem

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, nested-function, vue-options-api

I have Component.vue that i need to test:

```
Component.vue

<script setup>
const someFunction = () => {
   //...some code i do not want to execute
}

const functionTotest = () => {
   if(someCondition) {
      someFunction()
   }
}

</script>
```

The purpose of my test (Jest + vue test utils) is to check if `functionToTest` works ok - does it actually call `someFunction` if someCondition === true.

I tried mocking someFunction:

```
const wrapper = mount(Component, {
         global: {
            mocks: {
                someFunction: jest.fn()
            }
         }
})
```

but then when i call `wrapper.vm.functionToTest()` it still calls original someFunction() from Component.vue and not the mocked one that I provided in global.mocks.
How can i deal with this problem without refactoring Component.vue?

Comment: You should not test the implementation details of your component. You rather should test the "end result" aka interactions to other files/components/APIs. In this instance, you should test the "consequences" of the `//...some code i do not want to execute`. So if `someFunction` calls a pinia store actions, you have to mock that store, and assert wether the given store action is called or not.